# Shell scripts scheduler

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, workflow, oozie

Basically, I need to run a set of custom shell scripts on ec2 instances to provision some software. Is there any workflow manager like oozie or airflow with api access to schedule the same. I am asking for alternatives like oozie and airflow, as those are that of hadoop environment schedulers and my environment is not. I can ensure that there can be ssh access from the source machine that will run the workflow manager and the ec2 instance where want to install the software. Is there any such open source workflow schedulers?

Comment: Airflow is _not_ specific to Hadoop AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) for your use case. There are multiple provisioning solutions built on top of it. For example [Banzai Cloud Pipeline Platform](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/introduction-to-cadence/)

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.